# Symlinked MySQL column

Tags: mysql, postfix-mta

Because postfixadmin is asking for column names different from the ones I've already been using in my mail server, I'm looking for a way to easily mask / symlink / duplicate a column to a second name.

The example:

```
mysql> select * from virtual_aliases;
+----+-----------+----------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | domain_id | source         | destination       | created             | modified            |
+----+-----------+----------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |         1 | alias@domain | me@domain       | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
```

Postfixadmin wants the column name "address" which I believe refers to the information I've labeled as "desitnation", although if someone know's I'm wrong on that please tell me. Rather then change that column name and risk breaking existing configurations, I'd like some way to get the name "address" to refer to this colum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alias your columns but you have to list them out:

```
select id, domain_id, source, destination as address, created, modified from virtual_aliases;
```

Another option is to create a view that aliases the columns and query that instead of your actual table.

```
create view postfix_virtual_aliases as
    select id, domain_id, source, destination as address, created, modified from virtual_aliases;
```

Then you just query the view instead of the table:

```
select * from postfix_virtual_aliases;
```

A third option is to simply create a new 'address' column, copy all the data to that new column, and then create triggers to copy the value of 'destination' to 'address' on inserts and updates.